# Word2vec: add external word to every context

Tags: nlp, word2vec

I'm looking for a simple "hack" to implement the following idea: I want to have a specific word appear artificially in the context of every word (the underlying goal is to try and use word2vec for supervised sentence classification).

An example is best:

Say I have the sentence: `"The dog is in the garden"`, and a window of 1.

So we would get the following pais of (target, context):

```
(dog, The), (dog, is), (is, dog), (is, in), etc.
```

But what I would like to feed to the word2vec algo is this:

```
(dog, The), (dog, is), **(dog, W)**, (is, dog), (is, in), **(is, W)**, etc.,
```

as if my word W was in the context of every word.

where W is a word of my choosing, not in the existing vocabulary.

Is there an easy way to do this in R or python ?

Comment: Something similar to "Context Enrichment" in this? http://aclweb.org/anthology/R/R15/R15-1029.pdf

Comment: Yes very much so, thanks a lot for the link ! Basically my idea seems to be a particular case of their "enriched context".
Now I wonder if I actually have to roll up my sleeves and code it myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagined you have list of sentences and list of labels for each sentence:

```
sentences = [
    ["The", "dog", "is", "in", "the", "garden"],
    ["The", "dog", "is", "not", "in", "the", "garden"],
]
```

Then you created the word-context pairs:

```
word_context = [("dog", "The"), ("dog", "is"), ("is", "dog"), ("is", "in") ...]
```

Now if for each sentence you have a label, you can add labels to context of all words:

```
labels = [
    "W1",
    "W2",
]

word_labels = [
    (word, label)
    for sent, label in zip(sentences, labels)
    for word in sent
]

word_context += word_labels
```

Unless you want to keep the order in word-context pairs!

Comment: That is indeed the preliminary step I want to do with the sentences before feeding them to a skip-gram algorithm. Are you aware of an implementation that could take these tuples as input (and not just the raw sentences) ?

Comment: This one for example?
http://www.katrinerk.com/courses/introduction_to_computational_linguistics_spring_2012/ics12_schedule/python-code-creating-a-vector-space-representation

Comment: Aha now I understood your question! sorry I think you should code it. the link that I sent you is not word2vec. it is an example of how to create these word pairs. I am not sure. maybe there is a way to train with word pairs in Gensim.

Comment: You are right. I'm still fairly new to nlp in general but it seems gensim does   take tokens as input. Will dig into it. Thx a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the 'Paragraph Vectors' algorithm – implemented as the class Doc2Vec in Python gensim. In it, each text example gets an extra pseudoword that essentially floats over the full example, contributing itself to every skip-gram-like (called PV-DBOW in Paragraph Vectors) or CBOW-like (called PV-DM in Paragraph Vectors) training-context.

Also take a look at Facebook's 'FastText' paper and library. It's essentially an extension of word2vec in two different directions:

First, it has the option of learning vectors for subword fragments (chracter n-grams) so that future unknown words can get rough-guess vectors from their subwords.

Second, it has the option of trying to predict not just nearby-words during vector-training, but also known-classification-labels for the containing text example (sentence). As a result, the learned word-vectors may be better for subsequent classification of other future sentences.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I think gensim's implementation could be what I'm looking for, especially if I can reuse the same label for multiple paragraphs (do you know if that's possible?). I will take a look at FastText.

Comment: Yes, you can re-use labels (called 'tags' at Doc2Vec training time), or give each text a unique tag but then train a classifier to learn a mapping from  those tag-vectors to labels.